# Integration with salesforce with AEM 6

Tags: salesforce, integration, aem

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with AEM 6.0 as per this link:

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/integration/third-party-services/salesforce.html

But I am getting this error:

18.03.2015 12:01:40.181 *ERROR* [JobHandler: /etc/workflow/instances/2015-03-18/model_163017207920287:/home/users/geometrixx-outdoors/aaron.mcdonald@mailinator.com/profile] com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler Process execution resulted in an error
com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: Process execution resulted in an error
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:218)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobUtil$1.run(JobUtil.java:365)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I read the previous discussions but I didn't get that what could be the setting for  Day Commons HTTP Client 3.1. I also tried using SSL enabled proxy https://127.0.0.1:5433/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html.

Any reply will be great help.

Regards,

Sandeep Sahu

Comment: Hi, I have done this as a part of PoC, but didn't use this configuration Day Commons HTTP Client 3.1 . Just Enabling the SSL worked.

Comment: I have tried enabling ssl but didn't worked. Can you please suggest some steps towards this. may be I should try again.

Comment: This blog can help you to enable SSL . http://vivekdhimaan.blogspot.in/2015/02/enable-ssl-in-aem6.html

Comment: I tried again. 
1. Enabled SSL
2. Successfully created salesforce configuration in aem.
3. Salesforce connected app created successfully.
4.AEM got successful connection with salesforce.
5.strated the workflow(with correct setting) for exporting AEM user as lead to salesforce, got error: jobhandler. and workflow is in STALE state.

Comment: Now what to do??  Your suggestion will be great help.

Comment: you may debug it more, set logger and debug the jars provided by aem for the integration, find where workflow is breaking. Also look over the mapping configuration for user<-->lead. Or try to create user in aem with properties required to create a lead. As a payload select the profile node. Remember this node must have the properties that required to create lead. You can get sufficient information from adobe docs and from http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/integrating-salesforce-with-cq5/